# How to control google play leaderboard log in

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-games

I followed a tutorial in connecting to google leaderboard but a lot of tutorials are using the old google play services library.  I manage to sign in to google using this code but it appears upon starting the app.  Where should I put the googleAPIclient code so that I can log in when I click a button inside the game. I use libgdx and if anyone can link a tutorial that uses a new google play services library It would help a lot. I seemed to be stuck with this one.  Thank you!

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new RBGame(this,this), false);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);
    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    //layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to get it going is to use `BaseGameUtils` which you can download [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) (it is located in `/BasicSamples/libraries/`).

The [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) documentation describes how to use it. You still don't **have** to use `BaseGameUtils`, you could just use it as a reference for coding your own. But using it seems to be the way Google wants it done - probably to provide some consistency across games :)

Personally, I don't like using the `BaseGameActivity` as a base for my own activities and allowing it to take over the sign-in flow completely. I just use the `GameHelper` class to perform the required functionality on demand.

Comment: I already tried that one but when it comes to using gameHelper.getGamesClient() code it is undefined.  Am I missing something or the gamehelper is not updated I'm not sure.

Comment: Use `gameHelper.getApiClient()` instead, which returns a `GoogleApiClient` if you need to use it directly. Otherwise just make use of the various methods defined by `GameHelper`.

Comment: I'm trying this one and I think I'm on the right track but I don't know how to setup the gamehelper is this right? gameHelper = new GameHelper(this,GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL); and then gameHelper.setup(this); in the OnCreate method. Thanks!

Comment: That should do it for starting up. Then, whenever you want to just call the `gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn()` method to sign in. One note though, be sure to call the `gameHelper.onActivityResult` from your activity's `onActivityResult`, otherwise the sign-in won't work properly - the internal states need to be updated when sign-in flow returns. Also make sure you've added all the required items to your manifest.

Comment: ***@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
// create game helper with all APIs (Games, Plus, AppState):
gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);                                 View gameView = initializeForView(new RBGame(this,this), false);
gameHelper.setup(this);}***   I did this code but the game crashes on startup. I followed  [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371896/libgdx-google-play-game-services-android)

Comment: Did you add BOTH the `games` and `appstate` ID entries to the manifest? What error are you getting in logcat (maybe edit your question above and add it)?

Comment: yes this is the metadata ***<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>*** I installed the app on my device but when I start the app it says Unfortunately the app has stopped

Comment: You are missing the `<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />` tag. This one is required when using cloud save (which you are since you use `CLIENT_ALL`). You will need to provide Logcat output if this still does not work - saying it stopped provides no info on why.

Comment: I got it. I missed that metadata. It is working now thank you very much sir!